# Is it possible to use modal page in Tabbed pages in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

As what my title says, is it possible to use modal page when you click a tab in Xamarin Forms?

What I would like to do it when I click one of my 5 tabs it would open a Modal page. If it's possible can someone please show my some example of how it is done or point me to the right way.

Comment: I think you could make this work, but it sounds like a really horrible UX.  I would really reconsider any design that calls for this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possibile but a bit tricky.

1. Create a blank page (for example FakePage) and add it to the `TabbedPage.Children`
2. In the TabbedPage code behind override `OnCurrentPageChanged`, check when your fakepage is selected, then open a Modal.
3. When the modal is opened tell your `TabbedPage` to go back to the previous tab (so when the user closes the modal it doesnt see a blank page)

**Your tabbed page childrens**

```xaml
<views:Page1 Title="First tab" />
<views:Page2 Title="Second Tab" />
<views:FakePage Title="Modal tab" />
```

**Tabbed page code behind**

```cs
    private Page _lastPage;
    protected override async void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        if (CurrentPage is FakePage)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new YourModalPage());

            //Wait a bit for the modal to open, then reselect the last tab
            //This is useful when a user close the modal: you dont want to show a blank page
            await Task.Delay(150);
            CurrentPage = _lastPage;
        } 
        else
        {
            _lastPage = CurrentPage;
        }

        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what Giampaolo said, the following method might be a bit smoother:

```
protected override async void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        if (CurrentPage is FakePage)
        {

            CurrentPage = _lastPage;
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new YourModalPage());

        }
        else
        {
            _lastPage = CurrentPage;
        }

        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
    }
```

That way, you won't ever see the blank fake page during the transition.